# Google Cloud DLP Re-identify PII data using Deterministic encryption

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp, pii

I was experimenting with Google provided the article to re-identify Credit Card Number using Deterministic encryption using AES-SIV

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-cloud-dlp-de-identification-transformation-templates-pii-dataset#creating_a_key_encryption_key_kek

Accordingly, I have created a google DLP template to de-identify data and in the test option of the template it is working if we provide a 3 line csv with correct header names [I am using record type template]

[DLP Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4ytI.png)

[DLP Template Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtdCG.png)

As per the following link and video provided, the same template can be used to re-identify the data back to the original

> "Cloud DLP can perform both de-identification and re-identification on
> an entire column using a RecordTransformation without a surrogate
> annotation."

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/pseudonymization#cryptographic-hashing

But when we tried the same, it is re-encoding it again to a newly encoded value as per below.

[DLP Template Re-identify Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NDKu.png)

**Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can re-identify PII using Deterministic encryption using AES-SIV successfully**

Note: This was the same behavior I got when I continued through the article ahead and did not work as expected in the blog to re-identify the data

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/validating-de-identified-data-bigquery-re-identifying-pii-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-authenticate on the console, you need to use the API for this. And, because you don't use surrogate prefix, you have to rebuild your table in JSON (and it's boring to do... Or you can script it).

You have the full detail of the [API here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.content/reidentify)

---

The JSON to summit: the table (your deidenticated table and the template use)

```
{
  "item": {
    "table": {
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "name": "phone"
        },
        {
          "name": "email"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "stringValue": "1"
            },
            {
              "stringValue": "ASoxvJC6oo4fCgKm+ppgT6j2lSqdj179SbLc"
            },
            {
              "stringValue": "ARkspehZ720J0f/r5zqlVN65PS756cxQDbwSniZ+g8iV"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "stringValue": "2"
            },
            {
              "stringValue": "ATfmBVs25TEGYHLu+6DBBhpq6dk8LSJq+XyR"
            },
            {
              "stringValue": "AZZhJLTmQKjlcXEROCRPu9u81G98/SBac/AlWXwtgiYe"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "reidentifyTemplateName": "projects/<YOUR_PROJECT>/locations/global/deidentifyTemplates/test-email-DeId"
}
```

*I saved the content in a file named: `dlpdata.json`*

The curl request to call the API

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json"  \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
     -X POST -d @dlpdata.json \
     https://dlp.googleapis.com/v2/projects/<YOUR_PROJECT>/content:reidentify
```

Comment: Does content:reidentify and content:deidentify differ internally in their logic? i.e is it similar to decode and encode respectively? Because I have noticed on closer examination that there are two methods in Templates

Comment: There are two methods in Templates Definition deidentifyConfig and reidentifyConfig. But in the example provided and the Console -> Security -> Data Loss Prevention UI does not offer a reidentify config [Google DLP 4. reid-template.json](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-cloud-dlp-de-identification-transformation-templates-pii-dataset#creating_the_templates). Can you please let me know in the example google provided how can I make it work to reidentify the data. The example is not working

Comment: DeID and ReID are the same in their logic and JSON definition, but you call a different endpoint to perform the encode/decode operation. What is not working in my example? Did you update the content with your DeID data and your own template? What's the error code/message?