# How to de-identify the data present in Big query table

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

How to de-identify the data already present in Big query  table and then re-identify the same and load in other BQ table.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the following article ["Validating de-identified data in BigQuery and re-identifying PII data"](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/validating-de-identified-data-bigquery-re-identifying-pii-data#objectives)? This article is the 4th of a series of 4. So I recommend to take a look on this to know that are usefull for you. This is the first one ["De-identification and re-identification of PII in large-scale datasets using Cloud DLP"](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/de-identification-re-identification-pii-using-cloud-dlp)

Comment: Yes I have checked this.But my target is to pick the data from Bigquery itself and deidentify and load into other table.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using dataflow pipeline call deidentifyContent.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example by using ["de-identifying sensitive data"](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data) to de-identify the data with the following [transformations](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/transformations-reference#transformation_methods) which belongs to [Data Loss Prevention (DLP)](https://cloud.google.com/dlp) API and then insert them into BigQuery, however to re-identify the data is needed cryptographical tokens. To achieve this, you can use the supported [cryptographic methods](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/pseudonymization#supported-methods) in Cloud DLP:

- Deterministic encryption using AES-SIV
- Format preserving encryption
- Cryptographic hashing

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087130/google-cloud-dlp-re-identify-pii-data-using-deterministic-encryption), it was mentioned some keys and steps to achieve the transformation using the **Deterministic encryption** however you can use the one you prefer.

As it was answered, the easy way to do this is following the Dataflow pipeliene [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/validating-de-identified-data-bigquery-re-identifying-pii-data#objectives)

Last but not least, I share with you an example of how to de-identify by replacing the data generated by a faker library that I used to simulate your BigQuery data.

```py
from faker import Faker
from google.cloud import dlp_v2

fake = Faker()
dlp = dlp_v2.DlpServiceClient()

def create_fake_data(data_length=5):
    data = []
    headers = [
        {"name": "name"}, {"name": "email"},
        {"name": "credit_card"}, {"name": "credit_card_provider"},
        {"name": "phone"}]

    for i in range(data_length):
        data.append({"values":
                     [
                         {"string_value": fake.unique.first_name()},
                         {"string_value": fake.free_email()},
                         {"string_value": fake.unique.credit_card_number()},
                         {"string_value": fake.credit_card_provider()},
                         {"string_value": fake.phone_number()},
                     ]
                     }
                    )

    return {"table": {"headers": headers, "rows": data}}

def deidentify_with_replace(item):
    parent = "projects/julio-castor-mx"

    inspect_config = {"info_types": [
        {"name": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"},
        {"name": "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER"},
        {"name": "PHONE_NUMBER"}]}

    deidentify_config = {
        "info_type_transformations": {
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "primitive_transformation": {
                        "replace_config": {
                            "new_value": {"string_value": "[IDENTIFIED]"},
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    response = dlp.deidentify_content(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "deidentify_config": deidentify_config,
            "inspect_config": inspect_config,
            "item": item
        }
    )

    return response.item


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = create_fake_data()
    deidentify_data = deidentify_with_replace(data)
```

Please consider that the `InfoType` parameter define the DLP **detectors** that create the de-indentify. These detectors are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference#documents) and to de-indentify a table use the [`Table` object](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/ContentItem#Table).

You can see more examples in this [repository](https://github.com/googleapis/python-dlp)